# Prolog - Allowing lists L iff #L > n in setof/3

Tags: prolog-setof

```
likes(russel, wittgenstein).
likes(whitehead, wittgenstein).
likes(godel, wittgenstein).
likes(hardy, ramanujan).
likes(littlewood, ramanujan).

at_least_three_fans :-
    setof(X, Z^(fact(X, idol), fact(Z, idol)), admirers).
```

I'd like to have print only Z : Z = wittgenstein, *i.e.*, I'd like to have only the idols that have *3 or more* admirers. The output to the predicate above:

```
?- at_least_three_fans.
idol = wittgenstein,
admirers = [godel, russell, whitehead].
idol = ramanujan,
admirers = [littlewood, hardy].
```

The following occurred to me:

```
at_least_three([_,_|_]).
```

But how am I to use it?

Thank you.